# How can I download an episode of BBC Radio One (Flash based radio)

Tags: download, flash, internet-radio

I want to download the full audio of the following program:
http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/console/b012qmh7

Is there any program, extension or method that I can use to download said flash audio stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is a free audio and video recorder. Using it, you can play the audio of the url you mentioned and record it using Audacity.

Once you install audacity, read this: http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Recording_audio_playing_on_the_computer